# Only print max value (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to solve Eulor Question 5 about finding the biggest 3 digit palindromic.

This is my code.

```
def reverse(num):
  return int(str(num)[::-1])

for y in range (100,999):
    for x in range (100,999):
        if x*y == reverse(x*y):
            print(x*y)
```

It solves the prblem and gives the right value but also gives every other three digit palindromic.  I only want it to return the max. I tried using the following but it doesn't work.

```
print( max (x*y))
```

Any suggestions?

Note: I know this might not be the best way to solve it but it the way I did so I want to finish it with the same methodology.

Thanks to anyone that can give some guidance to a new user.

Comment: What about saving the result that is highest in a variable, and when the for-loop is done printing it?

Comment: Your attempted solution and most of the answers have an off by one bug - the range you're using goes from 100 to 998.

Comment: Do you mean project Euler Question 4 - Largest palindrome product?

Comment: @pvg doesn't matter he still gets the right answer

Comment: @EpsilonX that's absurd. The intent is exhaustive search, not declaring an inaccurate algo correct because it happens to return the right answer.

Comment: @pvg A way to optimize code is to remove excess iterations, so once you've done an exhaustive search you can decrease the number of iterations for maximum efficiency, my bad i was assuming an exhaustive search had been done and 998 * 998  gave the answer

Comment: @pvg, I think that whether an off-by-one error makes an entire algorithm incorrect is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No, it's a matter of correctness. You can either say you know something about your result space and make optimizing assumptions, which what the previous commented was talking about. Or you are doing an exhaustive search, in which case if your search is not actually exhaustive, your algo is not correct.

Comment: I'm not saying off-by-one errors are okay, I'm saying that they're not an indicator of a bad algorithm. It's an easy mistake to make, and (in this case) an easy mistake to fix.

Comment: I'm not sure who went and downvoted every single answer that recommended `max()`, but it was a disservice to Stack Overflow. :(

Comment: I don't know about that - my answer didn't even include the `range()` calls. Oh well.

Comment: Sorry you guys got downvoted, so did I. Thanks all for the help I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to keep track of the largest value:

```
def reverse(num):
  return int(str(num)[::-1])

largest = None
for y in range (100,999):
    for x in range (100,999):
        xy = x*y
        if xy > largest and xy == reverse(xy):
            largest = xy
print largest
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks everyone else, this one was first and pretty simple so just writing here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the maximum value as you go through the numbers and then print that at the end:

```
def reverse(num):
  return int(str(num)[::-1])
current_max=0
for y in range (100,999):
    for x in range (100,999):
        xy=x*y
        if xy == reverse(xy):
            current_max=max(current_max,xy)
print(current_max)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
current_max = 0

for y in range (100,1000):
    for x in range (100,1000): #range is half-open
        if x*y > current_max and x*y == reverse(x*y):
        #Note that python is lazy and will only evaluate
        #x*y == reverse(x*y) if x*y > current max.
        #which is good, because casting to a string and back again
        #is marginally slower than a simple int comparison.
            current_max = x*y
print current_max
```

You should keep track of the current largest max. The builtin `max` will find the largest thing *given to it* (whether as an iterable or as multiple arguments, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max))

Comment: Also, as a comment: In general, if you're looking for the max, maybe you want to start with the largest number and not the smallest number. Maybe :P

Comment: A better way to say this is that logical and is a short circuit operator, not that python is lazy, mostly because it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of printing, store each value into a list and then just print the max value in the list once you are done. Either that or keep a running 'largestValueSoFar' value.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of printing every number, keep track of your results. When the loop is done, print the last result.

```
def reverse(num):
  return int(str(num)[::-1])

result = 0  # add an variable to keep track of your results
for y in range (100,999):
  for x in range (100,999):
    if x*y == reverse(x*y):
        result = x*y

print(result)
```

Comment: ok, clearly i was much to slow since there are already plenty of answers. ;)

Comment: This only finds the most recent one, not the largest one.